# c# xmldocument load from url keep session

Tags: c#, xml, session

I am loading an XML document from a URL. When the URL is loaded, it launches an ActionResult withing the app. Is there a way to keep the session from before the ActionResult is called active within the ActionResult? I'll try to explain more clearly:

Calling_Function (session is active) has the line "xmlDocument.Load(url);" goes to:

ActionResult for the url (session is null) 'does some work, returns back to Calling_Function'

Calling_Function (session is active again)

I need to access some session variables within the ActionResult which cannot be in the query string as they are object arrays, but the session is null when it is called.

Comment: You need two documents. Open the 2nd URL in a new document that is different from 1st URL.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Do you mean xmlDocument.Load(url) needs to go to a different document? How would I do that?

Comment: XmlDocument doc1 = xmlDocument(url1);XmlDocument doc2 = xmlDocument(url2);

Comment: I'm only loading 1 url to an xml document though.

Comment: It sounded like from your posting that it was leaving the original URL and you wanted to get back to original URL.  By opening up a 2nd document you can navigate without affecting the fir URL.  Doesn't matter if your first URL was not XML.